# Where to write UI code in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I'm writing my first application in Objective-C for iOS 7 (I come from Java world) and I found a lot of tutorials where the UI code, like `UIButton`s and inputs, is written in the view controllers. Is it normal? I expected to create the visual components in the storyboards.

Comment: Follow these [tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials) will help you alot.

Comment: Storyboards will only allow you to do so much. I believe newer versions of xcode the templates now implement a `configureView` method that gets call in `viewDidLoad` but if it doesn't for me I normally implement something simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly normal.

You will soon discover that the visual designer provided by XCode is not all powerful and that code is a must in order to get some stuff done.

Also, depending on the type of project you are working on, it might simply be more convenient to create your UI in code rather than in the designer. For instance, if you are working on a project with several other people, you might have issues merging your storyboard, although Apple has made considerable inroads in minimizing such problems.

Essentially, the choice is up to you, but it is always a good idea to know what happens under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

You use storyboard if you want to use visual tools for creation UI.
View controller is the place when you can create UI programatically.

You can use both in the same project. All depends what works best for you.